# Помогите пожалуйста! Как сделать переключение между несколькими слайдерами битрикс?

Tags: битрикс

Есть блок в котором есть слайдер, при нажатии на кнопку ниже можно выбрать другой слайдер, то есть меняется картинки. Нужно реализовать его на битриксе. Сам в нём не силён, пробовал сделать через компонент news.list. Помогите решить мою проблему, какой компонент использовать.Прилагаю фото и ссылку на сайт с слайдером. Заранее спасибо!

[Ссылка на сайт](https://line-up.io/php-senior-developers/)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2):

Можно найти много примеров например вот https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/learning/course/index.php?COURSE_ID=95&LESSON_ID=7805&LESSON_PATH=7785.7805 .
(подобное делают постоянно и много всякой информации)

Смысл в том что bitrix у вас будет для хранения самих фото слайдера, и ссылок которые будут на ваших слайдах (из админки контенщик будет задавать слайды).

Например можно сделать инфоблок слайдеры, в нём добавить элементы которые будут слайдами, например детальная картинка элемента это сама картинка слайдера, детальное описание это урл ссылки, тут же можно задать сортировку элементу.
(если нужно несколько слайдеров на сайте можно создавать для каждого раздел инфоблока и в него добавлять определённые слайдеры, а код раздела указать в компоненте)

Что бы при такой реализации сделать слайдер нужен будет компонент news.list указываете в него созданный вами инфоблок, задаёте сортировку параметры кеша, укажите имя шаблона <придумайте любое> далее создадите шаблон.

Затем создайте в папке /local/templates/<шаблон вашего сайта>/components/news.list/<придумнное имя шаблона>/template.php , а далее в этом файле в массиве $arResult (можете сделать print_r и посмотреть содержимое) будут все нужные вам данные это урл на картинку и ссылка, добавьте в шаблон html код любого слайдера (при необходимости создайте в этом же шаблоне файлы script.js и style.css с кодом из вашего слайдера).

---

Если нужно менять слайдеры как по вашей ссылке, то можно в начале шаблона указать картинки слайдера (в div например), а далее js грохать один слайдер и инициализировать другой. Либо что более ресурса затратно рисовать в шаблоне несколько слайдером и js показывать скрывать слайдеры.